# Maintain aspect ratio of image with full width in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a query regarding  tag. I want an image to take entire width of parent which I do using alignSelf:stretch, but I also want the height to be according to the aspect ratio of the image. How can I achieve something like this?

So I want a way to specify the height as a ratio of the width of the Image.

Comment: Still no good answer here!

Comment: Found this [repo](https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image) that does a good job.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use `style={{ aspectRatio: 3/2 }}` for a horizontal image with width to height ratio of 3:2.

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#aspectratio

(Available in RN 0.40+)

Comment: Beautiful. I did this along with `flex: 1` with a container set to `flexDirection: 'row'`, and I was able to get my images to stretch 100% the width of the containing element with preserved aspect ratios. Thank you.

Answer (score 106):

```js
<Image
   source={require('../../assets/img/headers/image-1.jpg')}
   style={styles.responsiveImage}
 />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  responsiveImage: {
    width: '100%',
    // Without height undefined it won't work
    height: undefined,
    // figure out your image aspect ratio
    aspectRatio: 135 / 76,
  },

});
```

Comment: This answer was the one that opened my mind and solved my problem. A question arises, though, why does `height` need to be `undefined` for it to work? If we use, for example `height: X`, omitting `width`, it seems to work without the need of a `width: undefined`.

Comment: That `height:undefined` is the best kept secret. And I don't mean that in a good way.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt with 'aspectRatio', but I don't need 'height: undefined' for this to work - perhaps an update has fixed this?

Comment: Wondering if this is a bug with React Native?

Comment: FYI This will not work for react-native-web

Comment: *figure out your image aspect ratio* how?

Comment: You can use `height: auto` instead more explicit

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why I had to add <<height>> as undefined

Answer (score 37):

I like **bdv**'s approach and I use this kind of images almost everywhere in my app. That's why I created an own component which is using `onLayout` to also support device rotation.

```jsx
import resolveAssetSource from "resolveAssetSource";
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Image, View } from "react-native";

export default function FullWidthImage(props) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const onLayout = useCallback((event) => {
    const containerWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width;

    if (props.ratio) {
      setWidth(containerWidth);
      setHeight(containerWidth * props.ratio);
    } else if (typeof props.source === "number") {
      const source = resolveAssetSource(props.source);

      setWidth(containerWidth);
      setHeight(containerWidth * source.height / source.width);
    } else if (typeof props.source === "object") {
      Image.getSize(props.source.uri, (w, h) => {
        setWidth(containerWidth);
        setHeight(containerWidth * h / w);
      });
    }
  }, [props.ratio, props.source]);

  return (
    <View onLayout={onLayout}>
      <Image
        source={props.source}
        style={{ width, height }} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can use it like this:

```jsx
<FullWidthImage source={{ uri: "http://example.com/image.jpg" }} />
<FullWidthImage source={require("./images/image.jpg")} />
```

Or if you know the ratio like this:

```jsx
<FullWidthImage source={{ uri: "http://example.com/image.jpg"}} ratio={0.5} />
<FullWidthImage source={require("./images/image.jpg")} ratio={0.5} />
```

Comment: Thanks for making it easy to copy/paste the component 

Comment: What if source of Image need to be static image resource, using `require` like `require('../../some.png')`?

Comment: I have been using this approach since many months. This works fine, But it slows down the rendering of image. An image rendering with this approach takes more time (almost double) than an image rendering with hardcoded width-height (Test in 2G network/slow network for more noticeable difference). In need of best solution.

Comment: @KalpeshWadekar I've added a `ratio` attribute to my component. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Halt you can use Image.resolveAssetSource(this.props.source).
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997611/is-it-possible-to-using-image-getsize-with-static-image-file

Comment: @Halt I've updated the component to support static images resource.

Comment: On larger screens (in height) this solution leaves a blank space at the bottom (in portrait mode). any idea?

Answer (score 17):

It's actually pretty simple.

The `Image` class has a `getSize` method. [1]

Let's say that you've created a component for your `aspectRatioImage` and you calculate the appropriate values every time `componentWillMount` fires.

Then your code would look something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    Image.getSize(this.props.source.uri, (srcWidth, srcHeight) => {
      const maxHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height; // or something else
      const maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

      const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
      this.setState({ width: srcWidth * ratio, height: srcHeight * ratio });
    }, error => {
      console.log('error:', error);
    });
  }
```

So now that the image height and width are saved in your component's state, you can just run

```js
 <Image
   style={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }}
   source={this.props.source}
   resizeMode="cover"
 />
```

[1] - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize

Comment: I edited your post so I could remove my downvote, which I did. I didn't think that the image dimensions were properly state (still not sure about that) but saw that the docs suggested this approach.

Comment: @MattParrilla it depends a little on what you will be using it for. I can imagine you want to use this to 'scale' an image until it hits it's bounds somewhere on the screen. In that case state will do fine. If it's to display a static image, then it would make more sense to pass it as props I think.

Comment: This method work well if the image is still on the screen. I have encountered issue where the image getSize is still being process, the user swap to other screen, the setState now setting to a value to a component that is unMounted. I was hoping the Image component itself have a much cleaner way to scale the height according to the width of it parent. The solution above work really well for a fix image location. it causing so much warnings when we implement the image resizing dynamically in a FlatList where the component unmount any item that is not on the screen to reduce the memory footprint

Comment: the only valid answer

Answer (score 7):

In my case i also had to set height to 'auto' :

```
{
    width: 200,
    height: 'auto',
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the image height based on the width/height ratio.

So if the image originally is 200x100, after setting its resizeMode to stretch:

```js
var deviceWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width;

...

myImage {
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceWidth * 0.5
}
```

I know maybe it is not the best practice, but it helped me a lot with images of all sizes that needed to mantain a certain relation with other images, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, doing the following would give us an image rendered to max width/height depending on orientation while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image itself:

```js
render(){
    return(<Image style={{'width': Dimensions.get('window').width, 
                         'height': Dimensions.get('window').height}}
                  resizeMode='contain'
                  source='[URL here]'
           </Image>);
}
```

Using 'contain' with resizeMode: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Update: * Unfortunately, it seems that there is a common bug with resizeMode's 'contain' specifically when using react native for Android: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5738*

Comment: This gives a tonne of whitespace above & below the image? (on iOS)

Comment: the solution propose above just trying to fit the image to the whole screen which is not what the question is all about. The question is related to how to resize the image with the same aspect ratio as the original image into the given width

Answer (score 5):

You can use [react-native-scalable-image](https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image). The following example will do the job:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';

const image = <Image width={Dimensions.get('window').width} source={{uri: '<image uri>'}} />;
```

Answer (score 4):

With `resizeMode='contain'` and `flex=1` I get the image in full width while keeping the aspect ratio.

```js
  <Image
     source={{ uri: 'URI' }}
     resizeMode="contain"
     style={{flex:1}} />
```

The image need to be in a container View with flex or height defined, so the flex of the image can work.

Answer (score 2):

```
const RespImage = ({ offer }) => {

const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

    let image_url = `YOUR_IMAGE_URI`;

    Image.getSize(image_url, (srcWidth, srcHeight) => {

        const maxHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        const maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

        const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
        setHeight(srcHeight * ratio);
        setWidth(srcWidth * ratio);
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ height: height, width: width, marginBottom: 20, resizeMode: "contain" }}
                source={{ uri: image_url }}
            />
        </View>
    )
```

}

Comment: Works like a charm! And quote from the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#getsize) "In order to retrieve the image dimensions, the image may first need to be loaded or downloaded, after which it will be cached. "

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/) in my React Native (v0.62+) project.

I needed to specify a square `aspectRatio` for `Image` components that had a defined `width` and undefined `height`.

I found that styling `height:0;` achieved the "square image" result that I wanted:

```jsx
// Gallery container styled-component
const Gallery = styled.View`
  flexDirection:row;
  flexWrap:wrap;
`

// Square half-width image styled-component
const Photo = styled.Image`
  width:50%;
  height:0;
  aspectRatio:1;
`
```

This method also works for full width image styling - replacing `width:50%` with `width:100%` produces the expect result with correct aspect ratio of each image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the *Image.getSize* approach, but had problems, since we gather all the image links in a config file and then pass the ImageURISource into the source prop of the Image.

My solution for that was to wait for the Image onLayout callback to get it's layout properties and use that to update the dimensions. I created a component for that:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image, ImageProperties, LayoutChangeEvent, StyleSheet, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

export interface FullWidthImageState {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  stretched: boolean;
}

export default class FullWidthImage extends React.Component<ImageProperties, FullWidthImageState> {
  constructor(props: ImageProperties) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { width: 100, height: 100, stretched: false };
  }

  render() {
    return <Image {...this.props} style={this.getStyle()} onLayout={this.resizeImage} />;
  }

  private resizeImage = (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    if (!this.state.stretched) {
      const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
      const height = width * event.nativeEvent.layout.height / event.nativeEvent.layout.width;
      this.setState({ width, height, stretched: true });
    }
  };

  private getStyle = (): ViewStyle => {
    const style = [StyleSheet.flatten(this.props.style)];
    style.push({ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height });
    return StyleSheet.flatten(style);
  };
}
```

This will update the dimensions of the image to match the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case on RN 0.68.0 on iOS 16 I had to do this in order to make the image show up properly in proper aspect ratio and fill the available width.

Setting aspect ratio directly on the `<Image>` element did not work.

`imageSource` is an object made from `Image.getSize()` i.e. `{uri, width, height}`

```
// ....
{imageSource && (
        <View
          style={[
            styles.imageContainer,
            {
              aspectRatio:
                (imageSource.width ?? 1) / (imageSource.height ?? 1),
            },
          ]}>
          <Image source={imageSource} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
      )}
// ...


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 2 * spacing,
  },
  imageContainer: {},
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let's create a component like this:

```
const ImageCustom = ({uri}) => {
const [ratio, setRatio] = useState(0);
  Image.getSize(
    uri,
    (width, height) => {
      setRatio(width / height);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('error:', error);
    },
  );
  return (
    <Image
      source={{uri: uri}}
      style={{width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: ratio}}
    />
  );
};
```

And call it like this

```
<ImageCustom uri={item}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Give aspectRatio and width to the parent view and add width and height 100% to the Image
If you want an image with width of 100 and height of 50

```
<View style={{ width: 100, aspectRatio: 2 }}>
  <Image 
     source={{ uri: '' }}
     style={{
       width: '100%',
       height: '100%'
     }}/>
</View>
```

Comment: The question specifies that the width of parent is not available so answer would not be valid according to that situation.

Answer (score -3):

Use `resizeMode='contain'`

```
<Image style={{height:'100%', width:'100%'}} resizeMode="contain" source={{uri:this.state.imgSource}} />
```

This will keep the original aspect ratio, with given width and height as max-height and max-width.

Answer (score -9):

You may use something like this:

```js
<View style={{height:200}} >
<Image source={require('image!MyImage') style={{ resizeMode:Image.resizeMode.ratio, flex:1 }}} />
</View>
```

Please not that you still have to set the height on the view container.

Comment: There is no `resizeMode.ratio` as per https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageResizeMode.js, so didn't work for me.