# I want to show network images with different aspect ratio. | I am working on React Native

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native

I have to show a list of network Images having different aspect ratio.
I have to maintain the aspect ratio of images with width = 100% of screen size.

**sample example:**

```html
<ScrollView>
  <Image source={{/* network image url */}} style={{width:100%, height=?}} />
  <Image source={{/* network image url */}} style={{width:100%, height=?}} />
  <Image source={{/* network image url */}} style={{width:100%, height=?}} />
</ScrollView>
```

I have to specify the height as per the official doc. But what is the best practice to set the height in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain aspect ratio of image with full width in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642685/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-image-with-full-width-in-react-native)

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)