# React Native Aspect fit image

Tags: react-native

```
    <Image
      style={{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        width: '25%',
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 75,
      }}
      source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
      resizeMode="stretch"
    />
```

https://snack.expo.io/rJCoC9S5-

How would i make the image width 25% of the parent, and the height to whatever that is needed to maintain the original width:height aspect ratio?

Comment: maybe you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556256/8323264

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642685/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-image-with-full-width-in-react-native/49700613

Answer (score 14):

You can edit the style of your image like this:

```
<Image style={style.image} source={require('.....')} />

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

`contain` is what you are looking for. But there are more options like `strech` and `cover`.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect Fill in iOS and Center Crop in Android by these lines of code.

image: {
flex: 1,
width: null,
height: null,
resizeMode: 'contain'
}

[image: Please have a look this output on three devices]

Comment: this is not keeping the aspect ratio for me

Comment: Wow I did not expect this to work at all, but when I used `height: null`, along with set `width` and `aspectRatio` values, it worked perfectly!